# Copying a table column in a report to another location in Reporting Services 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

We just upgraded from SQL Server Reporting Services 2005 to 2008 R2. One thing that you could do quite easily in 2005 was the ability to copy and paste columns in a table. However, with 2008 (R2 in this case), it seems that this ability is now missing with the Tablix control. It proved to be a huge timesaver in the past, and I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing (a setting somewhere), or was this actually removed from 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted the same question on the MSDN forums, got an answer (not the one I was looking for unfortunately):  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/7a9cde52-9830-4e16-bb66-52bd639f103b/